# Как настроить передачу видео с hdd видеорегистратора на ftp-сервер?

Tags: centos, ftp, ftp-сервер

Имеется видеорегистратор Activecam. На нем настроена передача видео на фтп. Но на сервере ничего нет, загрузки не происходит. Пассивные порты открыты от 30к до 60к и на роутере, и на FireWallD. Ниже прикладываю трассировку:

> 3:52:44.318460 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags [P.],
>   seq 1:266, ack 1, win 29200, length 265: FTP: 220--------— Welcome to
>   Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] —------—  13:52:44.363451 IP
>   xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 266, win
>   65535, length 0  13:52:44.920757 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 1:15, ack 266, win 65535, length 14:
>   FTP: USER user  13:52:44.920793 IP centos2.user.ftp >
>   xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags [.], ack 15, win 29200, length 0 
>   13:52:44.921025 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags
>   [P.], seq 266:306, ack 15, win 29200, length 40: FTP: 331 User user
>   OK. Password required  13:52:44.961144 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 306, win 65535, length 0 
>   13:52:45.508589 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
>   [P.], seq 15:34, ack 306, win 65535, length 19: FTP: PASS password 
>   13:52:45.545255 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags
>   [P.], seq 306:389, ack 34, win 29200, length 83: FTP: 230-This server
>   supports FXP transfers  13:52:45.559696 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35415 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 1017, win 65535, length 0 
>   13:52:45.559718 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35415: Flags [R],
>   seq 3919211640, win 0, length 0  13:52:45.560267 IP
>   xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 389, win
>   65535, length 0  13:52:46.139108 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 34:40, ack 389, win 65535, length 6:
>   FTP: FEAT  13:52:46.139205 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429:
>   Flags [P.], seq 389:622, ack 40, win 29200, length 233: FTP:
>   211-Extensions supported:  13:52:46.161028 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 622, win 65535, length 0 
>   13:52:46.776742 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
>   [P.], seq 40:45, ack 622, win 65535, length 5: FTP: PWD 
>   13:52:46.776937 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags
>   [P.], seq 622:656, ack 45, win 29200, length 34: FTP: 257 "/" is your
>   current location  13:52:46.860401 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 656, win 65535, length 0 
>   13:52:47.375678 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
>   [F.], seq 45, ack 656, win 65535, length 0  13:52:47.375821 IP
>   centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags [P.], seq 656:669, ack
>   46, win 29200, length 13: FTP: 257 Logout.  13:52:47.375862 IP
>   xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 45:52, ack
>   656, win 65535, length 7: FTP: CWD /  13:52:47.376030 IP
>   centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 656:688, ack
>   52, win 29200, length 32: FTP: 250 OK. Current directory is / 
>   13:52:47.376526 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35429: Flags
>   [F.], seq 669, ack 46, win 29200, length 0  13:52:47.377447 IP
>   xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 669, win
>   65522, length 0  13:52:47.378123 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429 >
>   centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 670, win 65535, length 0 
>   13:52:47.464780 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.],
>   ack 688, win 65535, length 0  13:52:47.976457 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35429
>
> > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [R], seq 10430771, win 0, length 0  13:52:47.976790 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 52:89, ack 688, win 65535, length 37: FTP: CWD
> >     Kukan/192.168.2.188/2018-06-07/  13:52:47.976950 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 688:750, ack 89, win 29200,
> >     length 62: FTP: 250 OK. Current directory is
> >     /Kukan/192.168.2.188/2018-06-07  13:52:48.066999 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 750, win
> >     65535, length 0  13:52:48.577012 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 89:96, ack 750, win 65535, length 7:
> >     FTP: CWD /  13:52:48.577208 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 750:782, ack 96, win 29200,
> >     length 32: FTP: 250 OK. Current directory is /  13:52:48.662526 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 782, win
> >     65535, length 0  13:52:49.179081 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 96:134, ack 782, win 65535, length
> >     38: FTP: CWD /Kukan/192.168.2.188/2018-06-07/  13:52:49.179272 IP
> >     centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 782:844, ack
> >     134, win 29200, length 62: FTP: 250 OK. Current directory is
> >     /Kukan/192.168.2.188/2018-06-07  13:52:49.278076 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 844, win
> >     65535, length 0  13:52:49.775594 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 134:142, ack 844, win 65535, length
> >     8: FTP: TYPE I  13:52:49.775765 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 844:874, ack 142, win 29200,
> >     length 30: FTP: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary  13:52:49.860773 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 874, win
> >     65535, length 0  13:52:50.374929 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 142:202, ack 874, win 65535, length
> >     60: FTP: SIZE AC-HR-1104_ch1_main_20180607195358_20180607220128.dav 
> >     13:52:50.375113 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 874:910, ack 202, win 29200, length 36: FTP: 550 Can't check
> >     for file existence  13:52:50.641980 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 874:910, ack 202, win 29200,
> >     length 36: FTP: 550 Can't check for file existence  13:52:50.664196 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 910, win
> >     65535, length 0  13:52:51.333249 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [P.], seq 202:210, ack 910, win 65535, length
> >     8: FTP: ALLO 0  13:52:51.333402 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 910:925, ack 210, win 29200,
> >     length 15: FTP: 200 A L'HUILE  13:52:51.359846 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 925, win 65535, length 0  13:52:51.926116 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 210:218, ack 925, win 65535, length 8: FTP: TYPE I 
> >     13:52:51.926273 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 925:955, ack 218, win 29200, length 30: FTP: 200 TYPE is now
> >     8-bit binary  13:52:51.959247 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 955, win 65535, length 0 
> >     13:52:52.527421 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 218:224, ack 955, win 65535, length 6: FTP: PASV 
> >     13:52:52.527722 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 955:1003, ack 224, win 29200, length 48: FTP: 227 Entering
> >     Passive Mode (192,168,1,3,199,83)  13:52:52.560317 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 1003, win
> >     65535, length 0  13:52:56.565101 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35434 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [S], seq 10431950, win 65535, options [mss
> >     1300], length 0  13:52:56.565136 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35434: Flags [S.], seq 1715635815, ack 10431951, win
> >     29200, options [mss 1460], length 0  13:52:56.565157 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [F.], seq 224, ack
> >     1003, win 65535, length 0  13:52:56.565296 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [P.], seq 1003:1016, ack 225, win 29200,
> >     length 13: FTP: 227 Logout.  13:52:56.566322 IP centos2.user.ftp >
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428: Flags [F.], seq 1016, ack 225, win 29200, length
> >     0  13:52:56.566928 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35434 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags
> >     [.], ack 1, win 65535, length 0  13:52:56.567000 IP
> >     xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 > centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 1016, win
> >     65522, length 0  13:52:56.567859 IP xxx-xxx.234.78.35428 >
> >     centos2.user.ftp: Flags [.], ack 1017, win 65535, length 0 
> >     13:52:56.568165 IP centos2.user.ftp > xxx-xxx.234.78.35434: Flags
> >     [P.], seq 1:266, ack 1, win 29200, length 265: FTP: 220--------—
> >     Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] —--------

Comment: 1. вы не по адресу: обращайтесь к производителю п.о. для вашего регистратора. 2. либо не используйте это давно окаменевший эксремент под названием *ftp*.

Comment: по поводу первого я вас понял. чем можно заменить фтп?